# How can I use the Apply() function for this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, apply

I have a df, with random portfolios, they are shown as follows

> ```
> >>> random_portafolios
>
>     AAPL weight  MSFT weight  XOM weight  JNJ weight  JPM weight  AMZN weight  GE weight  FB weight T weight
> 0     0.188478     0.068795    0.141632    0.147974    0.178185     0.040370   0.020516   0.047275  0.166774
> 1     0.236818     0.008540    0.082680    0.088380    0.453573     0.021001   0.014043   0.089811  0.005155
> 2     0.179750     0.071711    0.050107    0.089424    0.080108     0.106136   0.155139   0.073487  0.194138
> 3     0.214392     0.015681    0.034284    0.276342    0.118263     0.002101   0.057484   0.000317  0.281137
> 4     0.301469     0.099750    0.046454    0.093279    0.020095     0.073545   0.178752   0.146486  0.040168
> 5     0.132916     0.006199    0.305137    0.032262    0.090356     0.169671   0.205602   0.003686  0.054172
> ```

the random portfolios have different weights

I also have the one-year returns on these actions

> ```
> >>> StockReturns.head()
>
>                 AAPL      MSFT       XOM      TWTR       JPM      AMZN        GE        FB         T
>    Date
>   2017-01-04 -0.001164 -0.004356 -0.011069  0.025547  0.001838  0.004657  0.000355  0.015660 -0.005874
>   2017-01-05  0.005108  0.000000 -0.014883  0.013642 -0.009174  0.030732 -0.005674  0.016682 -0.002686
>   2017-01-06  0.011146  0.008582 -0.000499  0.004681  0.000123  0.019912  0.002853  0.022707 -0.019930
>   2017-01-09  0.009171 -0.003170 -0.016490  0.019220  0.000741  0.001168 -0.004979  0.012074 -0.012641
>   2017-01-10  0.001049 -0.000335 -0.012829 -0.007429  0.002837 -0.001280 -0.002859 -0.004404  0.000278
> ```

Now I want to add two columns "Returns" and "Volatility" to that df. The returns and volatilities must be in function to the values of each row, and to do it for each row that there is.

He tried to use the Apply() function

```
def complex_computation():
    WeightedReturns = StockReturns.mul(arr, axis=1)
    ReturnsDaily= WeightedReturns.sum(axis=1)
    mean_retorns_daily = np.mean(ReturnsDaily)
    Returns = ((1+mean_retorns_daily)**252)
    cov_mat =StockReturns.cov()
    cov_mat_annual = cov_mat*252
    Volatility= np.sqrt(np.dot(arr.T, np.dot(cov_mat_annual, arr)))
    return Returns, Volatility
```

What I'm looking for is that this result appears in a row that corresponds to it (row 0, in this case), and do the same for the following rows that I have. Python `def complex_computation():` said that `name 'Returns' is not defined`

After

```
def func(row):
    random_portafolios['Volatility'].append(Volatility)
    Returns, Volatility = complex_computation(row.values)
    return pd.Series({'NewColumn1': Retturns,
                  'NewColumn2': Volatility})
```

and

```
def run_apply(random_portafolios):
    df_result = random_portafolios.apply(func, axis=1)
    return df_result
```

How could I run my code correctly?

Help me!

Comment: My first reply would've been to not use loops but to write a function an `apply()` it to the dataframe. But after a search I found this neat post: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/

Perhaps this will be of a little help to you.

Comment: Thank you very much @jho You could explain to me a little more how I would have to do my functions, excuse me, I'm hardly a beginner. I will be very grateful to you

Comment: In `complex_computation` you would calculate Returns and Volatility, which you both return. In `func` you would map those values to the columns.

Comment: Thank you @jho. Sorry I'm still stuck with this problem

Comment: I did the function in this way: `def complex_computation():
    WeightedReturns = StockReturns.mul(random_portafolios, axis=1)
    ReturnsDaily= WeightedReturns.sum(axis=1)
    mean_retorns_daily = np.mean(ReturnsDaily)

    Returns = ((1+mean_retorns_daily)**252)-1
    cov_mat =StockReturns.cov()
    cov_mat_annual = cov_mat*252
    Volatility= np.sqrt(np.dot(random_portafolios.T, np.dot(cov_mat_annual, random_portafolios)))
    return Returns, Volatility `

Comment: The rest I show in the update of the question.